# Difference between @available and #available in swift 2.0

Tags: swift

Swift 2.0 allows availability checking by using `@available` or `#available`, but what is the difference between using `@available` and `#available`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use if `#available` to run version-specific code in small blocks, like the following :

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // use UIStackView for example
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

But what if whole methods are off limits, Or perhaps even whole classes? Swift 2 has these scenarios covered too, using the `@available` attribute.

```
@available(iOS 9, *)
func useStackView() {
    // use UIStackView for example
}
```

More details : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking

Comment: In short, `#available()` is a run-time check which returns a Boolean, and `@available()` is a way of generating compile-time warnings/errors if the user's target is below what you mark it with and they're not making the `#available()` check, eh?

Comment: @nhgrif "#available() return a boolean". Note I can do : if #available(...) {...} but I cannot do something like : if !(#available(...)) {...}